# Whether a series is convergent or divergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Is it true that if $\sum u_n$ is convergent, where $u_n$'s are positive real numbers then $\sum \dfrac{u_1+u_2+...+u_n}{n}$ is divergent?

I know that if   $\lim_{n\to\infty}u_n =0$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{u_1+u_2+...+u_n}{n}=0$ and it is the necessary condition for a series to be convergent.

Someone help please.

Comment: what if $u_i=0$ for all i

Comment: Is the assumption that $\sum_n u_n$ is convergent **to some $\ell>0$** ? Because if all the $u_n's$ are zero, for instance, well... On the other hand, if $\sum_n u_n \neq 0$, then it's not too hard to prove.

Comment: I have edited later that $u_n$'s are positive

Comment: Then it is actually immediate, since $u_1+\dots+u_n > u_1$. But the result still holds without the assumption, as long as $\sum_n u_n \neq 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\sum_{n\geq 1}u_n$ is convergent to some $\ell\neq 0$, for any $\varepsilon>0$ there is some $N_\varepsilon$ ensuring $\left|-\ell+\sum_{n=1}^{N}u_n\right|\leq \varepsilon$ for any $N\geq N_\varepsilon$. In particular, from some point on the terms of the series $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{u_1+\ldots+u_n}{n}$ have the same sign and their absolute values are greater than $\frac{\left|\ell\right|}{2n}$. Since $\sum_{n\geq N_\varepsilon}\frac{C}{n}$ is divergent for any $N_\varepsilon\geq 1$ and any $C\neq 0$, so it is the series $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{u_1+\ldots+u_n}{n}$ .

Comment: Isn't it exactly the same argument as in [my (Community) answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2312269/75808)?

Answer (score 2):

Hint. If $u_i\geq 0$ and $u_1>0$ then
$$\sum_{n=1}^N \dfrac{u_1+u_2+...+u_n}{n}\geq \sum_{n=1}^N \dfrac{u_1}{n}.$$

Comment: Indeed, with the positivity assumption, this is the "right" proof.

Answer (score 0):

The post has been edited to say the $u_i$'s are positive.  Under that assumption, $\sum \dfrac{u_1+u_2+...+u_n}{n}$ diverges because $\sum_{n=1}^m \dfrac{u_1+u_2+...+u_n}{n}>\sum_{n=1}^m \dfrac{u_1}{n}$ and the latter goes to infinity as $m\to\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

*Answering the more general question before the edit, where the $u_i$'s are not necessarily positive.*

This will be true under an additional assumption, namely that the series $\sum_n u_n$ converges **to a non-zero number**.

Indeed, suppose $\sum_{n=0}^\infty u_n = S\neq 0$ (without loss of generality, assume $S>0$), then we have that (by definition) there exists $N\geq 0$ such that $$\frac{S}{2} < S_n \stackrel{\rm def}{=} \sum_{k=0}^k u_k \leq 2S$$
for all $n\geq N$.

But then,
$$\frac{S_n}{n} \geq \frac{S}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{n}$$
for all $n\geq N$, so the series $\sum_{n}\frac{S_n}{n}$ diverges by comparison with the Harmonic series.